# Find out if using Azure Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, azure-activedirectory

We are looking for an easy way to find out if someone is using Azure Active Directory or Standard Active Directory.

If I spoke to a standard user with no admin privileges, is there a way they would be able to definitively tell what they are using?

This could be through:

- Visual interface clues
- Settings

[Access work or school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo469.png)

By going Settings -> Accounts -> Work or School, this seems like a promising way of getting this information, are there any scenarios where people may not be able to get to this information?